# Keep Focus back to the previous Textbox on failed validation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, c#-3.0

I want Focus back to the previous Textbox if validation gets failed. I am validating the Textbox control value on lostFocus event. Need some help.

This question was eralier too link is

[Keep Focus on Textbox after user tried to move to other control (on failed validation) in winforms, .net 3.5 WEC7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539284/keep-focus-on-textbox-after-user-tried-to-move-to-other-control-on-failed-valid#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attempt to focus an element inside its own `LostFocus` handler you will face a `StackOverflowException`, I'm not sure about the root cause (I suspect the focus kind of bounces around) but there is an easy workaround: dispatch it.

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (sender as TextBox);
    if (!theTextBoxWasValidated())
    {
        // doing this would cause a StackOverflowException
        // element.Focus();

        var restoreFocus = (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate { element.Focus(); };
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(restoreFocus);
    }
}
```

Through `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` you make sure that restoring the focus doesn't get in the way of the in-progress loss of focus (and avoid the nasty exception you'd face otherwise)